# Don't trigger a PR when target branch changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pull-request, cicd, bitbucket-server

I'm using Jenkins 2.209 with Bitbucket server 7.12.0
latly we changed to a multibranch pipeline
I've notice that when a PR is approved and merged into main all the other open PR's that targeting main are triggered.
Is there a way to tell jenkins not to trigger the PR when there is a change in the target branch?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways;

On the side of Bitbucket; you can take a look at what (web)hooks are set on a repo/project (via Repository Settings).

More likely; If you use the [Bitbucket plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket/) on Jenkins, I believe you can change the way PR's are build, per job config. Try setting Config -> Branch Sources -> Bitbucket -> Behaviours -> "Discover pull requests from origin" to "The current pull request revision"; or test with any of the additional "Behaviours"

But, to close off with; do you really want to do that? You may encounter that a PR is stable on the moment as it is created; but unstable after a while if the target has changed. Bitbucket will still show you the old green check-mark, and may fool you in a false sense of merge-security. It *might* be better if you let them run automagically. If versioning is the source of the headache; I would recommend a look at tools like Jgitver (for Java) to build versioning on the base of a git tag and/or (commit distance) instead of a pom.xml like file

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your pipeline in Branch Sources \ Build strategies . Add a "Change requests" and check the "Ignore rebuilding merge branches when only the target branch changed".

You can find it in the documentation [plugin-content-change-requests](https://plugins.jenkins.io/basic-branch-build-strategies/#plugin-content-change-requests).